# Cannot unit test my model in sailsjs

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, sails.js

For my sails app I'm using the following code to unit test the User model but got the error message:

'TypeError: Object # has no method 'create''

```
var User = require('../../api/models/User');
var Sails = require('sails');

console.log(User);

describe("User Model:", function() {  

  // create a variable to hold the instantiated sails server
  var app;

  // Global before hook
  before(function(done) {

    // Lift Sails and start the server
    Sails.lift({

      log: {
        level: 'error'
      },

    }, function(err, sails) {
      app = sails;
      done(err, sails);
    });
  });

  // Global after hook
  after(function(done) {
    app.lower(done);
  });

  describe("Password encryption", function() {

    describe("for a new user", function() {
      var user;
      before(function (cb) {
        var userData = {
          email: "testuser@sails.com",
          password: "test_password",
          passwordConfirmation: "test_password"
        };

        User.create(userData, function (err, newUser) {
          if (err) return cb(err);
          user = newUser;
          cb();
        });
      });

      it("must encrypt the password", function() {
        user.must.have.property('encryptedPassword');
        user.must.not.have.property('password');
        user.must.not.have.property('passwordConfirmation');
      });

      after(function (cb){
        user.destroy(function (err) {
          cb(err);
        });
      });
  });
```

As it seems to me that sails is correctly lifted, what is the problem causing the create method  not to be available ?

Comment: I am quite new to nodejs and trying to write some tests for an application that I am building. Would it be possible to have a look at your model, so that I can try and figure out how to write the tests for my models please. Thanks

Comment: unit tests should not spin up server or hit databases/do i/o

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Remove the first line:

```
var User = require('../../api/models/User');
```

Once Sails app is lifted, you will have your models available automatically, see [here](https://github.com/bredikhin/sailsjs-mocha-testing-barrels-fixtures-example), for example.

And in your case, your first line overrides the `User` model which would be otherwise constructed by Sails.js, that's why even though you have an object it's not a Waterline model.

Comment: I am facing same problem if I define test.js file under Test folder(Under any folder).Unable to reach User model ,shows Error"ReferenceError: User is not defined
".If i write var User = require('../api/models/User.js'); shows error "TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'create'
"

Comment: @tajuddin Please look at [this example](https://github.com/bredikhin/sailsjs-mocha-testing-barrels-fixtures-example/blob/master/test/index.js).

Comment: @FrancescoGramano you can try checking out [the whole repo](https://github.com/bredikhin/sailsjs-mocha-testing-barrels-fixtures-example) (it's been restructured) or also [this one](https://github.com/bredikhin/sails101-testing)