# SailsJS: Best way to seed initial users

Tags: node.js, models, sails.js, seeding

What is the proper way to seed the database with an initial admin/root user in a User model in Sails if one does not exist upon launch?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SailsJS best practice to seed database with data before other Models are initialized](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22941765/sailsjs-best-practice-to-seed-database-with-data-before-other-models-are-initial)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: I found the solution to this problem. Since models are created before bootstrap.js is run in the config folder, I can simply check if a User model with ID "root" already exists, and if not, use User.create() to create the user.

Long story short, just create the user in config/bootstrap.js BEFORE the callback cb().