# Best way to migrate table changes to production sailsjs tables

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline

I just lost 11,000 records from my database just running the command for sailsjs without the --prod part in it, So I thought I should ask whats the best way to change the tables on production server when the Model.js has been changed ?

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Automated migration should never be done in production. This a common-sense practice that applies to any production system with important data. There are a few solutions available for migrating a sails.js database.

1. [**sails-db-migrate**](https://github.com/building5/sails-db-migrate): db-migrate integration for sails.js

> db-migrate integration for Sails.js. This is a fairly simple wrapper, which provides grunt tasks for running and creating migrations.

2. [**sails-migrations**](https://github.com/BlueHotDog/sails-migrations): The missing, migrations arm of the octopus

> sails-migrations provides an easy way to manage database migrations with sails, based on the amazing https://github.com/tgriesser/knex lib. This means you can have fine-grained control over your schema/data transformations between versions.

3. [**Sequelize migrations**](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/migrations/)

> Sequelize 2.0.0 introduces a new CLI which is based on gulp and combines sequelize-cli and gulp-sequelize. The CLI ships support for migrations and project bootstrapping. With migrations you can transfer your existing database into another state and vice versa

Comment: So if I use one of these ways n sails V0.10.5 I do not have to ever worry about data loss from SailsJS restart in production mode ?

Comment: I'm trying this now https://github.com/building5/sails-db-migrate,, I just created a new API and now I'm trying to use this migrate tool to build the table for the new API. It does not work ?? Any thoughts ?