# Step by Step guide to using a migrating tool for production SailsJS system

Tags: node.js, sails.js, database-migration, waterline

I very new to production sailsjs environment, I need a way to add table changes which I make in my sailsjs Models in Dev to be applied to Sailsjs Production Models.

Does anyone dealt with this before ? Can someone guide me through it please ?

It would be really helpful to have a step by step guide,

All i need is to have the Model attributes created in the Production database tables.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to migrate table changes to production sailsjs tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29997983/best-way-to-migrate-table-changes-to-production-sailsjs-tables)

Comment: No, I need to know step by step guide,, The other answers just show me the fish,, not how to fish.. That's not useful in my case as a total newbie Travis. Sorry

Answer (score 1):

Well you can always jump in here: https://gitter.im/balderdashy/sails and you might find some help.